# HttpContext.Current return null

Tags: c#, httpcontext

I have Wcf service whose method isPOST and I call via Fiddler. I have this line:

```
string x = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(".");
```

and HttpContext.Current returns null. How can I solve this?

Comment: This should be all you need: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752234.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you [enabled ASP.NET compatibility on your service implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752234.aspx)?